# SQL stored procedure - Deleting each row that matches input list

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-delete

I need to make a stored procedure that takes a userId and a list of categoryIds, and
delete any row that matches, from a specific table.

Pseudo code:

```
@categorylist int[]
@userId int

foreach(category as c in @categorylist)
{
DELETE FROM HelpWith as h
WHERE c.categoryId = h.categoryId
AND h.userId = @userId
}
```

Now I know that you are not supposed to use loops in SQL (Not that this would work anyways...)
Does anyone know how to make a stored procedure that could do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL Server and versions 2008+ you can use [Table Valued Parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx)

```
CREATE TYPE Categorylist AS TABLE (ID int);
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE DoStuff
   @userId int,
   @list Categorylist READONLY
AS
...
DELETE FROM HelpWith 
      WHERE categoryId IN (SELECT ID FROM @list)
      AND userId = @userId
...
```

Comment: For some reason it keeps telling me "Incorrect syntax near '(' expecting AS, EXTERNAL, FROM or ID" . . . Which doesn't make any sense to me...

Comment: @user2392980: sorry, my bad syntax. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Seeing as this is a stored procedure and thus has to be run multiple times, does the TYPE (Categorylist) have to be deleted at the end of the procedure? 
I'm getting the "The type 'Categories' already exists, or you do not have permission to create it." -error after running the procedure a second time.

Comment: @user2392980 - The line `CREATE TYPE Categories AS TABLE ...` should only be run once.

Comment: Thing is if it isn't there, I get errors like:
"The parameter '@list' can not be declared READONLY since it is not a table-valued parameter" and if I remove READONLY:
"Parameter or variable '@list' has an invalid data type"

Comment: @user2392980 You create it like a normal table. Once for the database and then you don't run it when you run the procdure. It's persistant.

Comment: @NLwino Please see me previous comment :) 
If i just treat it like a "normal" data type, it won't work.

Comment: Oh... It was one of those errors, that gets ignored when you execute :P

Answer (score 4):

Make a table variable out of @Categorylist

```
@Categorylist table (ID int)

DELETE FROM HelpWith 
WHERE categoryId IN (SELECT ID FROM @Categorylist)
AND userId = @userId
```

Comment: And how would you add rows to the table variable in a stored procedure?

Comment: @gbn depends on what RDBMS you are using. And seems like you already answered your own question ;)